# Is it possible to send a php session variable directy with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, session

I've got this in index.php

```
    <?php

    include_once '..\connect.php';

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $player_name = $_SESSION['username'];

    } else {    
        header( 'Location: http://localhost/Inventory/index.php' ) ;
        exit;
    }

    ?>
```

and im making a ajax request to request.php

```
    <?php
    //connect to databate and check for errors
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con) {
        die ('Could not connect to database: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //select database and check selection
    if (!mysql_select_db ("GotA", $con)) {
        die ('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
    }

//I have to create this if not it doesnt find the sessions $player_name variable
    $player_name = $_POST['name']; 

    //***Create Player Array**//
    $player_info = "SELECT * from players where id = $player_name";
    $player_info2 = mysql_query($player_info) or die ('Couldnt get players name');
    $player_info3 = mysql_fetch_array($player_info2);
```

Well it just seems unsecure to retrive data from the databe using a variable sent with javascript isnt there a way to directly use the variable from the index.php (session part)?
or is it safe to just pass the information with javascript?

Comment: Please, PLEASE read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) and its accepted answer thoroughly. Understand it. Use it.

Comment: Thank you all for you comments and answers im going to read through them and the links ill report when i find the solution

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just retrieve the session again in request.php?

Instead of:

```
$player_name = $_POST['name'];
```

Use:

```
$player_name = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Also be sure to use `session_start()` before this.

Comment: Right, but I'm not talking about any JS here, only PHP. JS is just making a call to a PHP page, which _can_ access the session.

Comment: Jason, Correct, it *can* if it knows the session id and you call `session_id(hash)`. Just calling `session_start` will not re-instate the session because PHP sees AJAX as being it's own unique session.

Comment: I've never had to use session_id for something like this. The way I stated has worked fine for me in the past numerous times.

Comment: Then I may be incorrect and my usage was probably also incorrect. My apologies.

Comment: Just to clarify this point for any future readers of these comments: a `GET`/`POST` initiated by a user by typing a URL or clicking a link is no different than a `GET`/`POST` initiated by XmlHttpRequest. HTTP is HTTP. PHP does not assign an AJAX request its own session because it doesn't know that the request originated from a script (unless you build in the logic to do so in your PHP and JS code).

Answer (score 2):

From my previous experience using jQuery the session still works with an ajax request, as long as you `session_start()` at the top of the script being called you should be able to access the session variables.

Comment: pretty sure you're wrong...I'm 90% sure I've been able to set/get session variables using AJAX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX request, though it's coming from JavaScript, can still access your browser's session state. You can also fall back to a POSTed variable:

**request.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Set $dbuser and $dbpass in a secure configuration file
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=GotA', $dbuser, $dbpass);

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
    $player_name = $_SESSION['username'];
else
    $player_name = $_POST['name'];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * from players where id = :playername');
$stmt->execute(array(':playername' => $player_name));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

One other thing, having asyncronous session-aware requests can result in race conditions if you're running multiple asynchronous requests. See [this article](http://chipmunkninja.com/Troubles-with-Asynchronous-Ajax-Requests-g@) for information. As long as you're only reading session variables and not writing them (or explicitly ending the session), then you should be okay. *(If someone has a definitive answer for the previous statement, please share in the comments)*