# how to set session variable for click on image in gallery view and load to a new page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

when click a image form the gallery of image, i need load to another page along with setting the $_SESSION['IssueID'] something like this, i know by send it through URL (get method) but i don't want the user to know this 'IssueID' not even by  post method. how can i do it...

i saw some what similar to my query in this

[Setting a PHP $_SESSION['var'] using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery)

here i want load page with out data been shown to the user....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user won't see anything, if you use Ajax (or even the way shown on the other thread you linked), because it happens in the background.

Comment: Please provide some more informations, if my answer doesn't really help you

Comment: It's completely answered by Luke Dennis in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work. when click on the image nothing append.

Comment: then i could do post method from input type="image"

Answer (score 0):

1. Using cookies is simple technique .
2. mysql heap table which is a temporary table you can use this

Comment: i get value from db need store it in a session for that click of the image