# Get jQuery UI Datepicker selected date to a PHP Session variable?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How to get jQuery UI Datepicker selected date to a PHP Session variable when a date selected by user?

Comment: Yes. *Ask a yes/no question, get a yes/no answer.*

Comment: Related question with good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery

Comment: additionally you can utilize select event of the DatePicker UI to set the session using jquery.ajax or jquery.post whatever way you like to call the page

Comment: @DaveRandom Question edited... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an AJAX call when the onSelect is trigged.. Just dummy code you can play with:

```
        $('.selector').datepicker({
                 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                       $.ajax({
                             url: "myPHPscript.php?selecteddate=" + dateText,
                               success: function(){
                                 $(this).addClass("done");
                            }
                        });
                     }
        });
```

Comment: I dont know PHP but I give it a try. Create a file that is called myPHPscript.php and use: echo $_GET['selecteddate'];

Comment: The selecteddate variable will be passed thru QueryString http://ditio.net/2008/06/12/php-query-string/

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You can do this using `Ajax`. After the Datepicker is closed you can set the Session Variable using a Ajax call.

You can use the `DatePicker` event `onClose` if you want to set the variable after the dialog is closed or `onSelect` after a date is selected. I would prefer the `onClose` event.

#### Sample

**jQuery**

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $.post("/backend.php", {"VariableName": dateText});
   }
});
```

**PHP (backend.php)**

```
<?php
    // set the variable
    $_SESSION['VariableName'] = $_POST['VariableName'];
?>
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)