# Remember the date selected in datepicker even after refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I just want to know if how can my datepicker remembered what month has been selected. For example, I choose June 1, 2013 even after refresh the month to be displayed in date picker is still June.

Here is my code.

```
$(function() {
    
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#weekpicker').datepicker('widget').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }
    
    $('#weekpicker').datepicker( {
        
        changeYear:true,
        changeMonth:true,
        showButtonPanel:true,
        
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 7);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#weekpicker').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings )
                 + ' - ' + $.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
            
         selectCurrentWeek();   
     
        },
        
        beforeShow: function() {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek(); 
        }
    
    }).datepicker('widget').addClass('ui-weekpicker');
    
    $('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.ui-weekpicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });

    
});
```

Comment: There's no magic way,  you have to store it somewhere (cookie, local storage, db, window.name...)and restore the value when the page is loaded

Comment: I suggest you to put the selected date into an alternate field `altfield` that can be retrieved on your serverside:

    `$('#weekpicker').datepicker({ altField: "#actualDate" });`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to deal with sessions.

Once the website is refreshed, just add the date into a [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php).
You can read more about sessionsn [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and a more concrete example for what you are looking for, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159422/get-jquery-ui-datepicker-selected-date-to-a-php-session-variable).

Comment: This is one of many solutions,  one of the reasons this is not a good question for SO

Answer (score 0):

Well, you added a space to "" in the if statement. And I guess I have bad logic anyways - you should probably use "&&" instead of "||". So please use the following code exactly as is:

```
$('input[type=text][id*=myDate1]').datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "/Images/cal.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {    $('#HiddenField1').val(dateText) },
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showWeek: true,
                firstDay: 1

            });
            var theDate;

            if ($('#HiddenField1').val() != "" && $('#HiddenField1').val() != null) {
                theDate = $('#HiddenField1').val();
            }
            else {
                theDate = new Date();
            }
            alert(theDate);
            $('input[type=text][id*=myDate1]').datepicker("option", "showAnim", 'bounce');
            $('input[type=text][id*=myDate1]').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'dd/mm/yy');
            $('input[type=text][id*=myDate1]').datepicker("option", "altFormat", 'dd/mm/yy');
            $('input[type=text][id*=myDate1]').datepicker('setDate', theDate);
```