# How set session in jQuery and get in PHP

Tags: jquery

This is very basic question, but i am very confused with this.

Is this possible to set session in jQuery and get in PHP, If possible then how?

Currently i am using `$session.set('name','value');`

Comment: Is this not working? Try `$.session.set('name','value');`? Do you want to send this `name` variable to PHP?

Comment: may be ajax call  will do work for you

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery

Comment: @newtt $.session.set('name','value'); is not working. I want to set value through jquery and get through PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first,

To use `$session.set('name','value');` You need to use this plugin to have this functionality: [Jquery Session Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin)

Did you do that?

Also as the above examples stated, you may use ajax call alternatively.

Truly to say i personally use ajax calls

Here's a demo script for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function set_session(val)
   {
     $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/set_user_session",{'user_id':val},
             function(data)
              {
                 alert(data);
              });
   }
</script>
```

Now comes the php page;

```
<?php
class ajax extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

function set_user_session()
   {
     $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
     $_SESSION['logged_user_id'] = $user_id;
     echo "Session Have Been Set";
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you create the `$session` object you could.

Something like:

```
$session = {
  set: function(name, value) {
    // Make an AJAX call to a PHP function which sets $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Session is server side state management technique, it cannot be set directly though client side (means using JQuery).

But if you want to set the session using jquery before your server side code runs, you will have make another call (it can be ajax call) to server which carries the value to be saved in session and then in the success of this ajax call you can call your desired server code.