# Assign JavaScript Variable value into PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have this JavaScript below which does few things on my website. I need to assign the value from JavaScript into PHP Variable to be used in a SESSION.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallbackReverse(what) {
            rand = get_rand();
            text = "416-05-201-XXX";
            text = text.replace("XXX", rand);
            //Store it in session
            <?php $_SESSION["pin_number"] = "text"; ?>
        }
    </script>
```

Please help.

Comment: JavaScript is client side, while PHP is server side - you can't pass data directly from JavaScript to PHP. You need to use AJAX or similar to load the data from the JS into a PHP script which can then manipulate the data as you wish. [See here for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

You can't insert PHP code in javascript code, 
PHP is a server language and Javascript is a client language

The solution to do what you want is using AJAX and call a PHP page which execute your action - you can send parameters (i.e. text)

with jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mypage.php',
    data: {text: text},
}).done(function () {
    /* success code here */
});
```

Your script PHP called :

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$_SESSION['pin_number'] = $text;
```

Comment: i think the same, i suggest you to improve your answer with some line of code because the question is clearly made by a rookie developer.

Comment: indeed, added ajax and php example

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Javascript lives on the browser, PHP lives on the server, when you see the page (so when JS is executed), PHP doesn't exist anymore.

You should change the logic of your code.