# How to assign value of jQuery to PHP SESSION in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code I am Assigning a value to PHP but Not able to get in PHP SESSION. Tried all possible way. Also, I tried to set SESSION from javascript not get values.

```
 var designation = $("#Designation").val();
              <?php $_SESSION['lclDesignation'] = "<script type='text/javascrip'>alert(desi);</script>"?>
```

Comment: Use `ajax` to send data from js to php

Comment: I am not sending any value, just I am setting session and accessing that set value in another page.

Comment: do you want to assign js code to a session?

Comment: YES, js value to session

Comment: You got a typo. Please see `<script type='text/javascrip'>`.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500779/assign-javascript-variable-value-into-php-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500779/assign-javascript-variable-value-into-php-variable) if you search on SO you can find solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to directly assign session value. using AJAX to assign the session value. Please review below code

```
var designation = $("#Designation").val();
$.ajax({
  url: "session.php",
   type: "POST",
   data : {'designation' : designation },
  success: function(html){

  }
});
```

Then create the session.php file paste the below code

session.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['lclDesignation']=$_POST['designation'];
```

Comment: getting Undefined index: designation

Comment: Please implement & check updated answer

Comment: sessionStorage.setItem("lclDesiSession",$('#selDesignation1').val()); I am setting values in javascrip but not able access.

Comment: Yaa it's one of way. But it's not working some updated browser & IE. If you using ajax it's support all browser & mobile also.

Comment: your updated answer not working getting same notice as Undefined index: designation.

Comment: method POST is not working

Comment: It's working fine in our end. Are you include jquery library?

Comment: I have done in another way as using the new text box and assigning the value to that box and checking value. Thank you for your support