# Unable to populate $_SESSION with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, session, post

I want to update `$_SESSION` data using a jQuery post.
Eventually I [found this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery) as base for 'the system'.

I have created the following two files as a test:

t1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

/* After refresh, src should be visible */
echo print_r($_SESSION);
?>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<img class="foo" src="img.jpg" />
<img class="foo" src="img2.jpg" />
<img class="foo" src="img3.jpg" />

<script>
$("img.foo").onclick(function()
{
    // Get the src of the image
    var src = $(this).attr("src");

    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "img" in the POST data
    $.post("/t2.php", {"img": src});
});
</script>
```

t2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['imgsrc'] = $_POST['img'];
?>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't produce the src path after refreshing `t1.php`.
`$_SESSION['imgsrc']` keeps empty.

I have tried everything, maybe for getting something?
Hope you  can help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to attach a document ready handler + it's not `onclick` but `click`, add this to your code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("img.foo").click(function()
 {
    // Get the src of the image
    var src = $(this).attr("src");

    // Send Ajax request to backend.php, with src set as "img" in the POST data
    $.post("/t2.php", {"img": src});
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would also advise using `$("img.foo").on('click', function() { ... });` to avoid this stuff

Comment: You are not properly handling json

Comment: Indeed @Toumash I just picked this example from the jquery website seems valid: `$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`

Comment: Turns out @Daan & Toumash are correct!
Stupid mistake! Solution was to change the onclick method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am seeing json everywhere, but it is the best way to do the communication. 
Proper json handling from php will be

```
$post= file_get_contents('php://input');
$json= json_decode($post,true); // true means json will be assoc array
```

Then your script could be modified:

```
<?php
session_start();

$post= file_get_contents('php://input');
$json= json_decode($post,true);
$_SESSION['imgsrc'] = $json['img'];
?>
```

With this it will dwork for sure

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/t2.php",
  data: {"img": src},
  dataType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is this the best method to handle the post data? Will Google a bit more. :)