# How to session variable using jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

In my code i want to assign value of jquery variable to PHP variable and session that PHP variable and use it in another page.For session i am using jquery plugin jquery.session.js.But i am getting error like `TypeError: cookies[i].split is not a function`.

```
  $(function() {
     var certificate_id =123;
    $.session.set("myVar", certificate_id);
      alert($.session.get("myVar"));
    });
```

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information, where does this error occur? Where do you use the cookies[i].split function?

Additionally, you can't manipulate a PHP session variable directly using the jQuery session variable. Instead, you need to do this with a combination of AJAX and a PHP script. Please refer to [Setting a PHP $_SESSION['var'] using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607673/setting-a-php-sessionvar-using-jquery)

Comment: In my code i have added jquery.session.js plugin.In that `TypeError: cookies[i].split is not a function` error occurs.

Comment: I have refered that link but in that any one can see data response using web browser extension.

Comment: What is the use case you want to cover? You want to transfer data from the client to the server, this data can be monitored by the user. However, cookies and javascript variables could also be observed by users. I don't exactly understand what you want to achieve.